# Getting exception for Parsing into Double

Tags: java, parsing, exception

I wrote the following code to take input from user and parse it to double for further calculations. The problem is this program is giving me `java.lang.NumberFormatException` at compile time and this error `java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)`. I don't know why is this error is generated. So my questions are:

- What is the cause of this error?
- Why am I getting exception at compile time. In C++ if something went wrong, I would get exception at run time. I am unable to understand this behavior of Java.

Here is the code:

Note:

Multiplicand and Multiplier are JTextField

```
public void TakeInput()
{
     double a,b;
    String input1="1",input2="1";

    input1=Multiplicand.getText();
    input2=Multiplier.getText();

    a=Double.parseDouble(input1);// converting string input to double
    b=Double.parseDouble(input2);
   ....
}
```

When I click run or play button in eclipse, I get this exception. So thats why I am unable to give any input to these text fields

Regards

Comment: Quite sure the exception is thrown at run time... Anyway, what is result of `Multiplicand.getText()`?

Comment: a and b are double offcourse!

Comment: Maybe your input1 is having an empty string or non-numeric string. Post the values which you are giving as input to input1 and input2

Comment: For Run time I mean when the program is running. or the window has appeared in front of user.

Comment: When I click `run` or `play` button in eclipse, I get this exception. So thats why I am unable to give any input to these text fields

Comment: Exceptions occur at runtime, compiler errors at compile time. There is no evident reason (besides the lack of type information for `a` and `b` that shows there is a compiler error. At runtime there could be `NumberFormatException` if the text in `input1` or `input2` is not actually a number. Debug your code and you will easily find out.

Comment: Write print statement before `a=...` statement, or better use a debugger and place a breakpoint at `a=...` statement. You will be able to see value of `input1` and `input2`. Actually, the stack trace printed when exception occurred gives the reason of the exception also.

Comment: You should post the `getText()` methods for the `Multiplicand` and `Multiplier` classes.  The problem does not lie in your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click run or play button in eclipse, I get this exception.

Your initial values for `Multiplicand` and `Multiplier` must be valid `double` values for `Double.parseDouble` not to throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Note that if you wish to set the values in each `JTextField` to `1` you could do:

```
Multiplicand.setText("1");
Multiplier.setText("1");
```

Also, `NumberFormatException` is a runtime or *unchecked* exception. You could wrap your assignments in a `try/catch` block so that you can handle this exception gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

parseDouble declares the checked exception NumberFormatException. This means your method TakeInout needs to declare how it will deal with this. Either your method must declare that it can throw the exception or you need to put try/catch blocks around parseDouble.

You can read more about the differences [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `input1=Multiplicand.getText();` is a value which can be actually parsed to a `Double`. And if it can go wrong (user input values, for example), wrap the line in a `try/catch` block:

```
public void takeInput() {
    String input1="1", input2="1";
    input1 = Multiplicand.getText();
    input2 = Multiplier.getText();
    System.out.println("'" + input1 + "', '" + input2 + "'"); //log inputs
    double a, b;
    try {
        a = Double.parseDouble(input1);// converting string input to double
        b = Double.parseDouble(input2);

    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //either
        return;
        //or something like:
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        //and continue
    }

   ....
}
```